# Корректность работы функции millis() при подвисаниях

Tags: c++, arduino, микроконтроллеры

Я сделал таймер работы платы, работает он через функцию `millis()`. Я проверял его с помощью рандомных задержек `delay(random(0,5000))`, всё работает корректно. Так же у меня есть различные модули и библиотеки для работы с ними. К примеру ethernet модуль, для него есть функции отправки и получения пакетов, функции эти могут подвиснуть на какое-то время. Так вот вопрос, во время этих зависаний значение, возвращаемое функцией `millis()`, будет корректно, или оно может быть меньше, чем на самом деле прошло времени? Про rtc модули я знаю, но мне интересен вариант без него.

Answer (score 0):

Функция millis() работает на прерываниях от таймера-счётчика 0. Поэтому ошибки могут возникать, только если обработчик другого прерывания будет "подвешивать" микроконтроллер более чем на 1 миллисекунду.